# Converting Procedural code to a class file

Tags: php, class

I am trying to build a class file. I started out with this basic proceedural code that is working fine:

The code here is to calculate the minimum and maximum Longitude and Latitude from a give center point lon and lat and radius of 100 miles or 160.934 kilometers.

```
        $lat = 32.373591;    //Location latitude
    $lon = -88.743598;   //Location longitude

    $r = (160.934/6371);    //Radius distance in Km
    $latMin = $lat - $r;  //Calculate the minmum latitude
    $latMax = $lat + $r;  //Calculate the maximum latitude

    $latT = asin(sin($lat)/cos($r));  //don't know what this calculation is for

    //$lonTri = arccos((cos($r)-sin($latT)*sin($lat))/(cos($latT)*cos($lat));

    $lonTri = asin(sin($r)/cos($lat));

    $lonMin = $lon - $lonTri;
    $lonMax = $lon + $lonTri; //Calculate the Min and Max Longitude


    echo $lat . " Latitude<br><br>";
    echo $lon . " Longitude <br><br>";
    echo $r . " r <br><br>";
    echo $latMin . " Latitude Min<br><br>";
    echo $latMax . " Latitude Max<br><br>";
    echo $latT . " Latititude Total <br><br>";
    echo $lonTri . " lonTri <br><br>";
    echo $lonMin . " Lon Min<br><br>";
    echo $lonMax . " Lon Max<br>";
```

I want to convert this to a class file in PHP. I am not sure about my work an I want to make sure that the class can reproduce the calculation properly. My class file is looking like this

```
 class nextCityCal {

//Location latitude
public $lat;

//Location longitude
public $lon;

//Radius distance in Km
public $r = 0.0252603986815257;

//Calculate the minmum latitude
public $latMin = $lat - $r;

//Calculate the maximum latitude
public $latMax = $lat + $r;

//don't know what this calculation is for
public $latT = asin(sin($lat)/cos($r));


public $lonTri = asin(sin($r)/cos($lat));

//Calculate the Min and Max Longitude
$lonMin = $lon - $lonTri;
$lonMax = $lon + $lonTri;

//set the latitude to the value pulled from the database
public function setLat($lat){
    $this->lat = $lat;
}

//rerurn the latitude for processing
public function getLat(){
    return $this->lat;
}
//set the longitude to the valuse pulled from database
public function setLon($lon){
    $this->lon = $lon;
}

//Calculate the minimum latitude
public function calLat($lat, $r){
    if(!$lat){
        $this->calLat = $lat - $r;
        return $this->calLat;
    }
}


}
```

My question is about

```
$latMin = $lat - $r;
```

In the proceedural code it is straight math.
In the class file I converted it to

```
    //Calculate the minimum latitude
public function calLat($lat, $r){
    if(!$lat){
        $this->calLat = $lat - $r;
        return $this->calLat;
    }
}
```

Will this return the calculated results that I want? If no how do I go about adding to variables in a class file?

Comment: yes, it will, code like this:       <?php $lat = 32.373591; 
    $lon = -88.743598;  
    $r = (160.934/6371);  $new=new nextCityCal(); echo $new->calLat($lat,$r); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to keep the scope no greater than it's required usage for better readability and resource management.  You can use private or protected properties (variables) if you're not setting or reading them from outside the class.  And you can use locals inside of methods just as you would for a stand-alone function.  You can also use a constructor method (__construct)to initialize properties instead of doing it the the declaration - so you'll have one place to look to see all the initializations.